# Required Error Message in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, error-messages

Hi folks,
                Can anyone tell me how to show the custom error message(red color) in visualforce after disabling the show header and standard stylesheet?

Below is my VFP for getting Custom Error Message

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false"  >
<apex:pageBlock >   
    <apex:form >   
        <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>   
        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.lastname}" html-placeholder="Enter Your Last Name"/>   
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Submit"/>         
    </apex:form>     
</apex:pageBlock>   
</apex:page>
```

But It gives

[image]

I want to display error message in red color
For that What I've to do?

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Updated Code:

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/show-error-message-visualforce-page/

[image]

I hope this will help you for sure

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the following tag I believe

```
<apex:messages/>
```

Comment: @Micheal Gill: It gives same...I wanna display in red color

Comment: Can you not wrap it in a div or something and apply some CSS style

Answer (score 0):

set strandardStylesheets to true or remove it. that will give you desired result.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" standardStylesheets="true" showHeader="false"  >
```